# iOS UIkit custom segmented buttons

Tags: swift, uikit

[image]

I'm looking to create a view with these buttons. There is a background animation when one of the button touched.
Not sure how to do this.

Is custom segmented buttons the way to go?

Comment: Custom segmented controls are the way to go (not the default one), and you can find whole loads of them in many libraries. One famous one is HMSegmentedControl.

Answer (score 1):

I went with custom control

```
 import UIKit
protocol MSegmentedControlDelegate:AnyObject {
    func segSelectedIndexChange(to index:Int)
}

class MSegmentedControl: UIControl {
    private var buttonTitles:[String]!
    private var buttons: [UIButton]!
    private var selectorView: UIView!
    
    var textColor:UIColor = .black
    var selectorViewColor: UIColor = .white
    var selectorTextColor: UIColor = .red
    
    weak var delegate:MSegmentedControlDelegate?
    
    public private(set) var selectedIndex : Int = 0
    
    convenience init(frame:CGRect,buttonTitle:[String]) {
        self.init(frame: frame)
        self.buttonTitles = buttonTitle
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        updateView()
    }
    
    func setButtonTitles(buttonTitles:[String]) {
        self.buttonTitles = buttonTitles
        self.updateView()
    }
    
    func setIndex(index:Int) {
        buttons.forEach({ $0.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal) })
        let button = buttons[index]
        selectedIndex = index
        button.setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)
        let selectorPosition = frame.width/CGFloat(buttonTitles.count) * CGFloat(index)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.selectorView.frame.origin.x = selectorPosition
        }
    }
    
    @objc func buttonAction(sender:UIButton) {
        for (buttonIndex, btn) in buttons.enumerated() {
            btn.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)
            if btn == sender {
                let selectorPosition = frame.width/CGFloat(buttonTitles.count) * CGFloat(buttonIndex)
                selectedIndex = buttonIndex
                delegate?.segSelectedIndexChange(to: selectedIndex)
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.selectorView.frame.origin.x = selectorPosition
                }
                btn.setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
}

//Configuration View
extension MSegmentedControl {
    private func updateView() {
        createButton()
        configSelectorView()
        configStackView()
    }
    
    private func configStackView() {
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttons)
        stack.axis = .horizontal
        stack.alignment = .fill
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        addSubview(stack)
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    private func configSelectorView() {
        let selectorWidth = frame.width / CGFloat(self.buttonTitles.count)
        selectorView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 8, width: selectorWidth, height: 32))
        selectorView.backgroundColor = selectorViewColor
        selectorView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        selectorView.layer.opacity = 0.5
        addSubview(selectorView)
    }
    
    private func createButton() {
        buttons = [UIButton]()
        buttons.removeAll()
        subviews.forEach({$0.removeFromSuperview()})
        for buttonTitle in buttonTitles {
            let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            button.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(MSegmentedControl.buttonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            button.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)
            button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)

            buttons.append(button)
        }
        buttons[0].setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)
    }
    
    
}
```

Usage:

```
private let segControl: MSegmentedControl = {
    let segControl = MSegmentedControl(
        frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 240, width: 280, height: 50),
        buttonTitle: ["Average","Total","Pending"])
    segControl.textColor = M.Colors.greyWhite
    segControl.selectorTextColor = .white
    return segControl
}()
```

To access index change event:
Implement the delegate on parent view:

```
       addSubview(segControl)
       segControl.delegate = self
```

Delegate:

```
   func segSelectedIndexChange(to index: Int) {
        switch index {
        case 0: print("Average")
        case 1: print("Total")
        case 2: print("Pending")
        default: break
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]